# Having issues with start mariadb on Mac os

Tags: macos, mariadb

I am trying to use mariah on Mac os.After I use brew to install marinade.
I run the start server command.And I got the error.This is what i got from the error log:

```
161206 12:15:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.19/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.19-MariaDB) starting as process 20734 ...
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.32-79.0 started; log sequence number 1606768
2016-12-06 12:15:15 123145377161216 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded    
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/servers from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist in engine
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 48: Address already in use
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-12-06 12:15:15 140736096797632 [ERROR] Aborting

161206 12:15:17 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/PhildeMacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
```

Really don't know what happened here......

Comment: Did you shutdown the MySQL/MariaDB that came with the OS?  Is this an "upgrade"?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ps aux | grep mysql`?